# Copy after use of overload operator fails (segmentation fault)

Tags: c++, templates, segmentation-fault, gdb, valgrind

I have a complicated code with the following function (some algorithms are probably wrong, but it's the technical side the problem):

```
template<int L>
string toStringBase(const StaticUnsigned<L>& x, int base) { //between {2,...,16}
   assert(2 <= base && base <= 16);
   StaticUnsigned<L> t, q, _base, _base_to_n;
   _base = (uint64_t)base;
   t = x;
   q = t;
   string str = "";
   _base_to_n = 1LL;
   char digits[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};
   while(t > StaticUnsigned<L>(0ULL)) { 
      q = t % _base; //The problem is here!
      std::cout << "Partial conversion = " << str << std::endl;
      str += digits[q.mem[0]];
      t = t / _base; //right shift
   }
   return str;
}
```

The `%` operator is overloaded as follows:

```
template<int L>
template<int M>
inline StaticUnsigned<MaxInt<L, M>::value> StaticUnsigned<L>::operator %(
   const StaticUnsigned<M>& _m) const
{
   StaticUnsigned<MaxInt<L, M>::value> rval, x, y;
   x = *this;
   y = _m;
   if (y > x) {
      return x;
   } else {
      rval = x / y;
      rval = x - rval * y;
      return rval;
   }
}
```

And in this specific case I have the copy constructor implemented as follows

```
template<int L>
inline StaticUnsigned<L>::StaticUnsigned(const StaticUnsigned<L>& _m)
{
   set_ui_const(this->mem, _m.mem, L, L);
}
```

Now... what happens is the following (from the gdb)... I basically call the function `toStringBase` and the related function is called, once the line `q = t % base` is reached the operator `%` is properly code, and in my specific case the `else` statement is properly called (specifically the assignment to the `rval` variable is fine, even the content is correctly computed. However I assume a copy of the variable `rval` is actually returned. This variable however is not assigned to `q` in the related statement. Valgrind returns

```
0000000000000000 000000000000000a 
==5613== Invalid read of size 8
==5613==    at 0x4012D7: set_ui_const(unsigned long*, unsigned long const*, int, int) (basic.cc:320)
==5613==    by 0x404C9B: StaticUnsigned<75>::operator=(StaticUnsigned<75> const&) (static_unsigned.h:205)
==5613==    by 0x404F1D: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > toStringBase<75>(StaticUnsigned<75> const&, int) (static_unsigned.h:453)
==5613==    by 0x373635343332312F: ???
==5613==    by 0x23B3A3937: ???
==5613==    by 0x7FEFFEFCF: ???
==5613==    by 0x7FEFFF04F: ???
==5613==    by 0x373635343332312F: ???
==5613==    by 0x4645444342413937: ???
==5613==  Address 0xffffffffffffffd0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==5613== 
==5613== 
==5613== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==5613==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFD0
==5613==    at 0x4012D7: set_ui_const(unsigned long*, unsigned long const*, int, int) (basic.cc:320)
==5613==    by 0x404C9B: StaticUnsigned<75>::operator=(StaticUnsigned<75> const&) (static_unsigned.h:205)
==5613==    by 0x404F1D: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > toStringBase<75>(StaticUnsigned<75> const&, int) (static_unsigned.h:453)
==5613==    by 0x373635343332312F: ???
==5613==    by 0x23B3A3937: ???
==5613==    by 0x7FEFFEFCF: ???
==5613==    by 0x7FEFFF04F: ???
==5613==    by 0x373635343332312F: ???
==5613==    by 0x4645444342413937: ???
==5613==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==5613==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==5613==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==5613==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==5613==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 10485760.
==5613==
```

The address: `0xffffffffffffffd0` is supposed to be address of the copy of the `rval` returned. But I don't understand why, the copy constructor should be fine.

By the way the class `StaticUnsigned` looks like (just a scratch, not all methods are reported):

```
template<int L>
class StaticUnsigned {
public:
   StaticUnsigned(); //ok
   template<int M>
   StaticUnsigned(const StaticUnsigned<M>& _m);
   StaticUnsigned(const StaticUnsigned<L>& _m); //ok
   template<int M = 64> //ok
   StaticUnsigned<MaxInt<L, M>::value> operator%(
      const StaticUnsigned<M>& _m) const;
   template<int M = 64>
   StaticUnsigned<L>& operator=(const StaticUnsigned<M>& _m); //ok
   StaticUnsigned<L>& operator=(const StaticUnsigned<L>& _m); //ok
public:
   uint64_t mem[(L + 63) / 64];
};
```

And the `set_ui_const` is basically an array copying.
Any clue on how I could debug the problem? I don't really know what to look at.

Update : operators `=`

```
template<int L>
template<int M>
inline StaticUnsigned<L>& StaticUnsigned<L>::operator =(
   const StaticUnsigned<M>& _m)
{
   if (this != (StaticUnsigned<L>*) (&_m)) {
      StaticUnsigned<M> tmp = _m;
      set_ui(this->mem, tmp.mem, L, M);
   }
   return *this;
}

template<int L>
inline StaticUnsigned<L>& StaticUnsigned<L>::operator =(
   const StaticUnsigned<L>& _m)
{
   if (this != &_m) {
      set_ui_const(this->mem, _m.mem, L, L);
   }
   return *this;
}
```

Update 2:

The function `set_ui_const`

```
void set_ui_const(uint64_t* y,const uint64_t* x, int ny, int nx)
{
   assert(nx >= 1 && ny >= 1);

   int Nx, Ny, Nmin, j, n2y;

   Nx = (nx + 63) / 64;
   Ny = (ny + 63) / 64;
   n2y = (ny - (Ny-1)*64);
   Nmin = (Nx <= Ny) ? Nx : Ny;

   for (j = 0; j <= Nmin - 1; j++)
      y[j] = x[j];
   for (j = Nmin; j <= Ny - 1; j++)
      y[j] = 0ULL;

   if (n2y != 64) {
      y[Ny - 1] &= (1ULL << n2y) - 1ULL;
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please *show* us the `set_ui_const` function? Also, with `L` equal to `75` (as it seems to be) then remember that `(75 + 63) / 64` is around `2.2`, your array is only `2` elements large. Will you only copy two elements? Or more?

Comment: Basically it stops to copy the first element (so the one with index `0`). But I'm sure the size is fine.

Comment: By the way, you should probably show us your assignment operator instead of the copy-constructor, as it seems to be the one leading to your problem according to the call-stack.

Comment: See the update, thx. The second one, is the one actually called.

Comment: To be honest I'm confused why the is the calling to the operator `=` the problem. The right operand of the operator `=` is the object with address `0xffffffffffffffd0` such object is kind of returned by the operator calling `%`. It must be something wrong with that return.

Comment: Could the problem be the fact I'm using as return value `StaticUnsigned<MaxInt<L,M>::value>` as a type?

Comment: Writing out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior* and could lead to *anything* to happen. And if you write out of bounds of data allocated on the stack then very little in the stack-trace could be counted on to be correct. The address `0xffffffffffffffd0` is highly unlikely to be a correct location of an object, and is a result of the UB you have, which is probably a stack smashing problem.

Comment: But as I said I don't see the reason for that happening. Maybe there's some subtle thing I'm missing.

Comment: The subtle thing you seem to be missing is the undefined behavior. And without seeing the `set_ui_const` we can't help you dismissing that function from the list of probably locations of the problem.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: I haven't actually stepped through the `set_ui_const` function in a debugger, but after reading it (with the variables replaced by their actual values) it doesn't seem like it goes out of bounds, or does anything else wrong. Which means your problem unfortunately is somewhere else. The problem *is* a stack problem though, which means somewhere else in your code you write out of bounds of some local stack-based variable. Since it's a stack-problem the call-stack you get and its contents is, as I said before, unreliable.

Comment: On an unrelated note, don't rely on `assert` for run-time correctness and checking. Release builds typically doesn't have `assert` enabled. Also, if you want an unsigned integer then you should probably use `unsigned` as the data type.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
==5613== Invalid read of size 8
==5613==    at 0x4012D7: set_ui_const(unsigned long*, unsigned long const*, int, int) (basic.cc:320)
==5613==    by 0x404C9B: StaticUnsigned<75>::operator=(StaticUnsigned<75> const&) (static_unsigned.h:205)
==5613==    by 0x404F1D: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > toStringBase<75>(StaticUnsigned<75> const&, int) (static_unsigned.h:453)
==5613==    by 0x373635343332312F: ???
```

*typically* means that you have stack buffer overflow somewhere. Note that the "return" address `0x373635343332312F` spells `"/1234567"` (without the quotes) in `ASCII`.

The best way to debug this kind of problem is with [Address Sanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer), supported by recent versions of GCC and Clang with `-fsanitize=address` flag.

Comment: Since I'm using a static compilation the `fsanitaze` doesn't work. What do the lines you highlighted mean? `0x4012D7` it reads the second argument at cell `[0]`. There is where I have the segmentation fault. I do know when the segmentation fault happen, but I don't understand why. Can't I use valgrind to perform a more accurate analysis? Could you suggest me how?

Comment: @user8469759 Do you have the string `/1234567` anywhere in your program? In the input for the program? Then you need to look at where that string is handled and make sure you have enough memory allocated for that string. Using `std::string` is a good place to start with. Or other [standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). In C++ you can mostly avoid pointers and dynamic memory handling these days, I suggest you try to refactor your code to not use pointers except when absolutely needed (calling C functions, polymorphism).

Comment: @Employed Russian, no such a string is not used at all. No input os such kind is used. No dynanic allocatio or deallocation is used.